# New girlfriend having constant jealous outbursts

Tags: dating, jealousy

I met a girl about a month ago that I met through some mutual friends which has been going well aside from her having jealous outbursts weekly regarding a girl a play on a team with. Granted she did tell me she does have trust issues

Within the first few days of seeing each other, an odd situation did arise. A male “friend”/teammate approached her while she was watching me play and got her to go with him to the bar to take shots and talk. When he asked about us and she said we were seeing each other, he immediately said that he and I were “competing for all the same women” recently and named at least two women I have played on a team with. This statement is completely false as I never did anything with them whatsoever and have been single for a few years. She discussed this with me and I was honest with everything I said. I mentioned I had coffee with one of them a month before we started seeing each other and this really began to bother her. She began to constantly ask if I had feelings for her, if I kissed her, etc which I never did. She snaps me from time to time which she seems to have a problem with me talking to her in general and we don’t honestly talk much. This includes me showing her my phone and everything.

A week later we’re at a bar and she checks a snap in front of me and tells me about this male coworker that messaged her and I notice she didn’t check a different message so I ask her and she reveals it was a guy she met at a bar weeks ago that she had been hanging out with frequently and had made out with. I got little upset being scrutinized over this girl while she never revealed this. She also lied when I asked if they slept together. She told me this a week later and basically said they were seeing each other when we met. Also said she made out with a friend of 20+ years during this time after a breakup. We talked and just decided to start over.

A week later she goes to the bar with a friend and the female teammate snaps me and says she’s at the same bar and thinks she recognizes my gf from a picture of us on social media. I said yes and was hesitant to tell my gf because of how she’s reacted to her even messaging me at all and figured my friend would probably just talk to her. She did not and when the bartender called this friend by her name my gf asked her if she knew me and they briefly exchanged words. She got pissed that I didn’t tell her she was there, accused me of talking about her behind her back and seemed to revel in the fact this friend was there with a guy and asked if it made me jealous. When she came over I showed her everything she sent me, including the compliments she said about my gf. She accused me again of having feelings for her etc and never had an answer for me whenever I asked what I could do have her trust me. I mostly got back that “there are ups and downs” “we need to communicate” but no real actionable solution.

Then last night as I was about to start playing this sport, she randomly asks when she snapped me last. I said two days ago and she accuses me of lying saying it was today. I show her again on my phone I was being truthful and she asks again if I have feelings for her and “she doesn’t know what we talk about”

We discussed this again for at least the 4th time today and all I can get back is that she will “try not to be jealous” and that maybe she should be closer to her guy friends. I’m losing hope that this is going to change and don’t know what else to do

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Interpersonal Skills! I'm not really sure what specific goal you are hoping to achieve here.

Comment: Were you giving her a taste of her own medicine by "She also lied when I asked if they slept together"? Are you trying to model the calm behavior you say you'd prefer? Do you believe her accusations will get better?

Comment: No I was a little shocked when she told me as we discussed if we had been seeing anyone recently before we met. More like it seems with an accusation there can tend to be a confession within it. It hurt being grilled so much over it when she actually had something to hide, though I appreciated she told me eventually. Had I not commented though? Maybe it would have been hidden. I have been calm and pragmatic when I do discuss this. Nothing seems to have changed any time we try to communicate regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Some people have a personality that drives them to create drama in their life. They do this as a way to deal with the anxiety issues they have. The emotionally dramatic way they go about tackling issues they feel anxious about makes them feel they are "addressing" the issue. But it's often a dysfunctional coping mechanism.

There are two main issues here you need to understand to empathetically deal with these kind of people:

1. They often have low self-esteem which manifests many insecurities that drives their anxiety.
2. They often react impulsively and communicate poorly, with emotional outbursts.

The above may seem very obvious and easy to understand, but it isn't easy to help someone understand these issues and teach them the skills necessary to deal with it. (And all that is based on the assumption that she doesn't have any psychological disorder, and is a "normal" flawed individual like all of us).

But, more importantly, I think you need to do some honest introspection too before trying to help her:

1. You are only in a month old relationship. Why are you treating it as a serious relationship where you feel the need take responsibility for your new GF's issues?
2. Despite her "passionate" outbursts to you about the relationship, she is already exploring other relationships and is obviously not committed to a relationship with you seriously (her words don't match her deeds). So why do you feel she is "the one" you have to fight for?
3. Contrary to popular belief long-lasting relationships don't survive on love. Mutual respect for each other is the secret for long-lasting relationships. Both of you clearly don't respect each other, and have doubts about it. Respect stems from acceptance. Do you honestly believe that both of you can learn to accept and respect each other?

It's true that the most common relationship advice on the internet is "dump them", but in your specific case, that would is an *option* you shouldn't disregard.

Yes, a relationship needs to be nurtured and needs constant attention and work to maintain it. And it is commendable that you want to fight for your relationship. But, as others have pointed out to you, you have only been dating this woman for 1 month. Unless you've known this woman for a long time (before you started dating), it's honestly not really mature to treat this as a serious committed relationship.

If your instincts are telling you that she is the one for you, without any doubts, then definitely should support her and fight for her.

Otherwise, treat it as new relationships should be, and be somewhat non-committal / detached to it and see how it goes. Help and support her as much as you can. But safe guard your own self-esteem, and make sure that her drama doesn't engulf your life to the extent you become a martyr. Be realistic that it is ok to end a relationship with someone who doesn't want to be helped, and that you don't get stuck in a relationship that is not salvageable.

Answer (score -1):

You met her a month ago and you're already exclusively dating? It seems that this relationship is moving at a very fast pace. You don't mention how old you and your gf are, but if she was meeting someone for drinks you're presumably adults. This is only my opinion as a fellow adult, but I think your gf is very needy and fairly controlling. My honest advice to you would be break it off with her, only because in my experience someone who's already acting like this 1 month in will only get worse.